# How to retain an filled values if page reloads in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

After validation, I display an error and return back to `:same` page. Some fields on the form are already filled, so I want to keep them filled while displaying error messages. Here is my controller code:

```
def signup
   @user=User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
     render "thanks", layout: "thanks"
   else
     flash[:notice] = "Unable to create an user, user name already exists. Try again!"
     render "signup", layout: "signup"
  end
end
```

My view code is as follows:

```
<%= form_for "user_signup" do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
<% end %>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is wrong. There should be at least two actions, one to display the form, the other to create the object.

Like this

```
def signup
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user=User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    render "thanks", layout: "thanks"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Unable to create an user, user name already exists."
    render "signup", layout: "signup"
  end
end
```

When `create` failed, signup template will be rendered, the `@user` instance in the template will be replaced by the failed one with incorrect fillings, and you will see all fillings kept.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the values in the controller somewhere(for instance in a hash) and when the view is rendered fill in the values of that hash if present. You would do something similar if you wanted to have default values for some of the fields.